# Why is WAMP opening localhost homepage, static html but not wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I have lost myself trying to setup WAMP in an effort to download a wordpress site. I had done this before but decided to reset my computer. Somehow I can't do it.

I copies static html to www directory and the site opens well. Wordpress also loads as long as the wp-config.php file is unaltered. (error establishing a database connection). As soon as the wp-config file is setup and made ready, the local host directory returns "Error connecting to the site" warning.

I have a feeling this might have to do with the php setting or sql but I do not know what to do. I have tried every search topic.

Sad thing is that I had two website perfectly set up following youtube tutorials just a few months ago. And now I can't do it.

Anybody here?? x

Comment: I would suggest you create a Virtual Host and then install WordPress into that

Comment: You are really not asking a question here! So there is nothing we can help with other than pointing you at a good tutorial and that is not allowed on SO

Comment: You should try installing Wordpress from scratch and import data from your previous installation afterwards

Comment: Hello all. Thank you for your reply and aplogies to RiggsFolly if that didn't sound like a problem. I have now linux and LAMP working on it fine. However, in windows, everything worked great until I imported the database from the live website. Thank you.